# Why can't I retrieve my flexible array member size?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer, sizeof, c11

OK so I was reading the standard paper (ISO C11) in the part where it explains flexible array members (at 6.7.2.1 p18). It says this:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
>   named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
>   flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member
>   is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more
>   trailing padding than the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or
>   `->`) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member,
>   **it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array
>   (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger
>   than the object being accessed**; the offset of the array shall remain
>   that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ from that
>   of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it
>   behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any
>   attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one
>   past it.

And here are some of the examples given below (p20):

> EXAMPLE 2 After the declaration:
>
> ```
>      struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure struct s has a flexible array member d. A typical way to
>  use this is:
>
> ```
>      int m = /* some value */;
>
>
>      struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to malloc succeeds, the object pointed to
>  by p behaves, for most purposes, as if p had been declared as:
>
> ```
>      struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```
>
> (there are circumstances in which this equivalence is broken; in
>  particular, the offsets of member d might not be the same).

*Added spoilers as examples inside the standard are not documentation.*

And now my example (extending the one from the standard):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct s { int n; double d[]; };

    int m = 7;

    struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m])); //create our object

    printf("%zu", sizeof(p->d)); //retrieve the size of the flexible array member

    free(p); //free out object
}
```

Online [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-x+c',source:'%0A++++%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A++++%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A++++%0A++++int+main()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++struct+s+%7B+int+n%3B+double+d%5B%5D%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++++++int+m+%3D+7%3B%0A%0A++++++++struct+s+*p+%3D+malloc(sizeof+(struct+s)+%2B+sizeof+(double+%5Bm%5D))%3B+//create+our+object%0A++++++%0A++++++%09printf(%22%25zu%22,+sizeof(p-%3Ed))%3B+//retrieve+the+size+of+the+flexible+array+member%0A++++++%0A++++++%09free(p)%3B+//free+out+object%0A++++%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Now the compiler is complaining that `p->d` has incomplete type `double[]` which is clearly not the case according the standard paper. Is this a bug in the GCC compiler?

Comment: That's interesting, but I don't see a clean way for compiler to actually know this size.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well according to the standard it seems that it should.

Comment: That's why it is interesting :) There should be some small letters somewhere..(there are some in your quote: *there are circumstances in which this equivalence is broken; in particular, the offsets of member d might not be the same*)

Comment: But nothing is said about applying the `sizeof` operator or the type of the array member in question. Only about some offsets.

Comment: Standard clearly states that operand of `sizeof` operator must be an object of complete type.

Comment: @haccks Did you read the quotes from the standard I've provided plus my whole post? Nowhere it is said that `p->d` should have incomplete type in the case.

Comment: Similar error message in **clang**: `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type
      'double []'`

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD; Where it says it has complete type?

Comment: @haccks *it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed* - It could be understood as *behaves as a complete type*.

Comment: @EugeneSh.; A string literal `char *s = "String"` behaves as `char const ss[] = "String"` doesn't guarantee that `s` and `ss` are equivalent.

Comment: @haccks We can clearly find the differences between the two, and they are well documented. This quote is stating the condition for the two cases to behave equivalently - usage of `.` or `->` operator. Nothing more

Comment: Note that C spec examples are not specifications.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "It could be understood as *behaves as a complete type*."  Not if there's no *object being accessed*.  `sizeof( p->d )` accesses no instantiated object, so that statement wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an **incomplete array type**;  ... C11dr 6.7.2.1 18

In the following `d` is an incomplete type.

```
struct s { int n; double d[]; };
```

> The sizeof operator shall **not** be applied to an expression that has function type or an **incomplete type** ... C11dr §6.5.3.4 1

```
// This does not change the type of field `m`.
// It (that is `d`) behaves like a `double d[m]`, but it is still an incomplete type.
struct s *p = foo();

// UB
printf("%zu", sizeof(p->d));
```

Comment: But the second quote seem to not apply if *that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed*, effectively making it a complete type. That comment in the code should be backed with something..

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Yes it, the field `d`,  behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array ....  That behavior does not change the fact is is still an _incomplete array type_

Comment: ok... what is "*behaves*"? For me if `A` behaves as `B`, then `A` is indistinguishable from `B` for an external observer.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Concerning " comment in the code should be backed with something".  I see it the other way around: the field type is at specified _incomplete array type_.  There is not specification that indicate it changes type - only behavior is detailed under certain conditions.

Comment: But the code `sizeof(p->d)` has a different *behavior* if `d` is flexible or fixed.

Comment: @Eugene Sh C11 does not define the behavior when `sizeof` is applied to a flexible field.  It is UB.  C does not specify a different behavior if `d` is flexible or fixed.

Comment: But how can we know this definition does not fall under this general "behavior" quote? There is no a clear exception about it. I am not saying it is wrong, but there seem to be an ambiguity (or even contradiction) in the standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118569/discussion-between-chux-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a defect in the Standard. We can see from the paper where flexible array members were standardized, [N791 "Solving the struct hack problem"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n791.htm), that the struct definition replacement is intended to apply only in evaluated context (to borrow the C++ terminology); my emphasis:

> When an lvalue whose type is a structure
>       with a flexible array member *is used to access an object*, it behaves as
>       if that member were replaced by the longest array that would not make
>       the structure larger than the object being accessed.

Compare the eventual standard language:

> [W]hen a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed [...]

Some form of language like "*When a `.` (or `->`) operator **whose** left operand is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and **whose** right operand names that member **is evaluated** [...]*" would seem to work to fix it.

(Note that `sizeof` does not evaluate its argument, except for variable length arrays, which are another kettle of fish.)

There is no corresponding [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm) visible via the [JTC1/SC22/WG14 website](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/). You might consider submitting a defect report via your ISO national member body, or asking your vendor to do so.

Comment: A broader problem which has never been addressed is that there's no consistent definition of "object" that adequately describes the behavior of allocated storage, which is the only context in which flexible array members are usable.  Given that the Committee hasn't managed to come up with a definition of "object" that fits modern interpretations of the aliasing rules, the problems with flexible array members seem minor by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Standard says:

C11-§6.5.3.4/2

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**.

and it also says
C11-§6.5.3.4/1

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an **incomplete type**, [...]

`p->d` is of incomplete type and it can't be an operand of `sizeof` operator. The statement

*it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed*

doesn't hold for `sizeof` operator as it determine size of the object by the type of object which must be a complete type.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is happening is correct in terms of the standard, arrays that are declared `[]` are incomplete and you can't use the `sizeof` operator.

But there is also a simple reason for it in your case. You never told your compiler that in that particular case the `d` member should be viewed as of a particular size. You only told `malloc` the total memory size to be reserved and placed  `p` to point to that. The compiler has obtained no type information that could help him deduce the size of the array.

This is different from allocating a variable length array (VLA) or a pointer to VLA:

```
 double (*q)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[m]));
```

Here the compiler can know what type of array `q` is pointing to. But not because you told `malloc` the total size (that information is not returned from the `malloc` call) but because `m` is part of the type specification of `q`.

Answer (score 0):

The C Standard is a bit loosey-goosey when it comes to the definition of certain terms in certain contexts.  Given something like:

```
struct foo {uint32_t x; uint16_t y[]; };
char *p = 1024+(char*)malloc(1024);  // Point to end of region
struct foo *q1 = (struct foo *)(p -= 512); // Allocate some space from it
... some code which uses *q1
struct foo *q2 = (struct foo *)(p -= 512); // Allocate more space from it
```

there's no really clear indication of what storage is occupied by objects
*q1 or *q2, nor by q1->y or q2->y.  If *q1 will never be accessed afterward,
then q2->y may be treated as a uint16_t[509], but writing to *q1 will trash
the contents of q2->y[254] and above, and writing q2->y[254] and above will
trash *q1.  Since a compiler will generally have no way of knowing what will
happen to *q1 in the future, it will have no way of sensibly reporting a size
for q2->y.